# Amazon S3 large image upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, amazon-s3, formidable

I am trying to upload images to Amazon S3.
The code I have works successfully for images of small size(approximately 30KB), however anything larger than that and it doesn't seem to receive all the bytes, the form.parse function isn't executed and the image does not get uploaded to S3.

I have searched Google for a solution but can't find anything that resembles my problem!

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', params: {Bucket: '[my-bucket-name]'}});

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.maxFileSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024;

form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected){
    console.log("received = " + bytesReceived);
    console.log("expected = " + bytesExpected);
});
form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    console.log("test");

    var playerID = fields.PlayerID;
    console.log("ID = " + playerID);

    var uploadfilepath = files.playerpic.path;
    console.log('File Location: ' + uploadfilepath);

    fs.readFile(uploadfilepath, function(err, file_buffer){
        if (err) { console.log(err);  }

        //Set parameters for uploading to S3
        var paramsS3 = {
            Bucket: '[my-bucket-name]',
            Key: playerID + "_" + n.toString(),
            Body: file_buffer
        };

        //Upload image to S3
        s3.upload(paramsS3, function(err, data){
            if (err) { return console.log(err); }
            console.log("We updated the bucket with this: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        });

    });

});
```

These are a set of typical results I'm receiving when an image won't upload to S3, but I cannot figure out why all the bytes aren't being received.

received = 1081

expected = 200507

received = 17081

expected = 200507

If anybody could help here and show me where I'm going wrong that would be very much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I am still not sure why this happened when using formidable, however I switched to using multer and the images uploaded without issue!